# Trouble putting JSON into a Rickshaw Graph on Dashing

Tags: ruby, dashing

I'm trying to create a [dashing](http://shopify.github.io/dashing/) dashboard based on some JSON data; however, I can't find a widget that supports these types of data sets (specifically using dates on the x-axis). I've tried [Rickshaw](https://gist.github.com/jwalton/6614023) but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Sample data:

```
[{"day"=>"2014-01-22", "users"=>120}, {"day"=>"2014-01-23", "users"=>130}, {"day"=>"2014-01-24", "users"=>110}, {"day"=>"2014-01-25", "users"=>175}]
```

Comment: cant you just manually parse the data and use the array in ruby?

Comment: Mainly I'm wondering how to use dates as the x-axis. So far all the examples I've seen are using integers. I'm trying to plot the last x-days worth of data over time. Do I need to convert dates into day 0, day 1, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Rickshaw documentation

> Note that the x values are interpreted as unix timestamps. Data can also be passed as full-on Rickshaw-style series.

This means you are providing wrong (as strings) the x axis values when you should provide them as Unix timestamps (as Integer). Also you must stick to **x** and **y** tuples syntax for the points.

Something like this JSON worked good for me for painting dates on X axis:

```
[{:x=>1430085600, :y=>0}, {:x=>1430172000, :y=>0}, {:x=>1430258400, :y=>11}, {:x=>1430344800, :y=>0}, {:x=>1430431200, :y=>0}, {:x=>1430517600, :y=>0}, {:x=>1430604000, :y=>0}, {:x=>1430690400, :y=>4}]
```